# Read in 4-byte words from binary file in Julia

Tags: file-io, binaryfiles, binary-data, julia

I have a simple binary file that contains 32-bit floats adjacent to each other.

Using Julia, I would like to read each number (i.e. each 32-bit word) and put them each sequentially into a array of `Float32` format.

I've tried a few different things through looking at [the documentation](http://julia.readthedocs.org/en/latest/stdlib/base/), but all have yielded impossible values (I am using a binary file with known values as dummy input). It appears that:

1. Julia is reading the binary file one-byte at a time.
2. Julia is putting each byte into a `Uint8` array.

For example, `readbytes(f, 4)` gives a 4-element array of unsigned 8-bit integers. `read(f, Float32, DIM)` also gives strange values.

Anyone have any idea how I should proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Julia Language has changed a lot since 5 years ago. `read()` no longer has API to specify Type and length simultaneously. `reinterpret()` creates a view of a binary array instead of array with desired type. It seems that now the best way to do this is to pre-allocate the desired array and fill it with `read!`:

```
data = Array{Float32, 1}(undef, 128)
read!(io, data)
```

This fills `data` with desired float numbers.

Answer (score 9):

(**EDIT 2020:** Outdated, see newest answer.) I found the issue. The correct way of importing binary data in single precision floating point format is `read(f, Float32, NUM_VALS)`, where `f` is the file stream, `Float32` is the data type, and `NUM_VALS` is the number of words (values or data points) in the binary data file.

It turns out that every time you call `read(f, [...])` the data pointer iterates to the next item in the binary file.

This allows people to be able to read in data line-by-line simply:

```
f = open("my_file.bin")
first_item = read(f, Float32)
second_item = read(f, Float32)
# etc ...
```

However, I wanted to load in all the data in one line of code. As I was debugging, I had used `read()` on the same file pointer several times without re-declaring the file pointer. As a result, when I experimented with the correct operation, namely `read(f, Float32, NUM_VALS)`, I got an unexpected value.

Answer (score 8):

I'm not sure of the best way of reading it in as `Float32` directly, but given an array of 4*n `Uint8`s, I'd turn it into an array of n `Float32`s using `reinterpret` ([doc link](http://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/stdlib/base/#Base.reinterpret)):

```
raw = rand(Uint8, 4*10)  # i.e. a vector of Uint8 aka bytes
floats = reinterpret(Float32, raw)  # now a vector of 10 Float32s
```

With output:

```
julia> raw = rand(Uint8, 4*2)
8-element Array{Uint8,1}:
 0xc8
 0xa3
 0xac
 0x12
 0xcd
 0xa2
 0xd3
 0x51

julia> floats = reinterpret(Float32, raw)
2-element Array{Float32,1}:
 1.08951e-27
 1.13621e11
```